# Simulate HTTP GET Responses using nginx or apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, http

Is it possible to create an Apache or nginx server which simulates the response codes I want? If it is, how hard is to setup and accomplish that in Mac OS?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to programmatically send different response to a client depedning on the request content, or do you wanto simply send (for example) a 500 to every request that comes in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any normal webserver that does that, but it's certainly possible to achieve that with mod_python:

http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-handler.html

This requires a little programming, but you just need to return appropriate code from the handler() function (which normally handles HTTP requests). I have quite often done this sort of stuff while web app programming and it just works.